# what is the actual OBFR loan rate fee?

Tags: loans, interest-rate, fees, federal-reserve

The OBFR for March 13 2020 was 1.10%. When a company takes a 1 million over night loan, so they pay 1.1% fee of $11,000, or is it annual like credit card and mortgage where the 1.1% gets divided by 365 and they pay 0.003% fee of $314?

https://apps.newyorkfed.org/markets/autorates/obfr

Comment: It is 1.10% APR, so the daily rate is approximately 1/365 as much (note that this is a leap year).

Comment: You should post that as the answer...

Comment: I can't find the authoritative definition that says it's APR, I just know that it is, because 1.1% *daily* would make it 100 times higher than mortgage rates etc when in fact it is the same order of magnitude.